# Keycloak: In RegistrationProfile class formContext.getUser() returning null

Tags: java, keycloak

I am implementing my own custom `RegistrationProfile` class, in order to grant the registering user a specific role depending on the information he inserted in the form.

I want to grant the role after making sure that the form is validated.
So I have put the code in the `success` method:

```
@Override
public void success(FormContext formContext) {

    UserModel userModel = formContext.getUser();

    MultivaluedMap<String, String> formData = formContext.getHttpRequest().getDecodedFormParameters();

    userModel.setFirstName(formData.getFirst(RegistrationPage.FIELD_FIRST_NAME));
    userModel.setLastName(formData.getFirst(RegistrationPage.FIELD_LAST_NAME));
    userModel.setEmail(formData.getFirst(RegistrationPage.FIELD_EMAIL));

    RoleModel roleModel = formContext.getRealm().getRole("user");

    userModel.grantRole(roleModel);
}
```

In the method `success(FormContext formContext)` when I do `formContext.getUser()` the method returns a `null`.

Could somebody help me understand why and how to solve this problem?
Maybe since the registering user is still not created, I am getting a `null`. But then how do I instantiate a `UserModel`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution:

Since the user needs to be created first, `formContext.getUser()` will always return `null`.
I have to first create a user then grant him a role:

```
String username = formData.getFirst(RegistrationPage.FIELD_USERNAME);

UserModel user = formContext.getSession().users()
        .addUser(formContext.getRealm(), username);

user.setEnabled(true);

user.grantRole(context.getRealm().getRole("user"));
```

My code is inspired by the `success` method of the [RegistrationUserCreation](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/master/services/src/main/java/org/keycloak/authentication/forms/RegistrationUserCreation.java) class.

Answer (score 0):

For me this turned out to be a configuration issue.

In the admin console :
Authentication -> Flows -> pick your custom action

Use the up and down arrows to make sure your custom action is after "Registration User Creation" (or else it won't be created properly).

It's also in the docs at
https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/index.html#modifying-extending-the-registration-form :

> Make sure your FormAction comes after "Registration User Creation" by
> using the down buttons to move it if your FormAction isn’t already
> listed after "Registration User Creation"